# Put loop result in a string in java

Tags: java, string, loops

I want to put the output of this for loop inside a string and print it at the end. however, it concatenating the old string value with the new one. How can I prevent this issue?
help, please!

```
while (tupleQueryResult.hasNext()) {
    BindingSet bindingSet = tupleQueryResult.next();
    for (Binding binding : bindingSet) {
        // Each Binding contains the variable name and the value for this result row
        String name = binding.getName();
        Value value = binding.getValue();
        result = name + " = " + value;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your variable **result** declared

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder to concatenate value pairs and print them :

```
StringBuilder string= new StringBuilder();
String name;
Value value;
while (tupleQueryResult.hasNext())  
{

    BindingSet bindingSet = tupleQueryResult.next();

    for (Binding binding : bindingSet)
     {
       name = binding.getName();
       value = binding.getValue();
       string.append(name);
       string.append(" = ");
       string.append(value);
       string.append("\n");   // to enter newline character
     } //for

 }  //while

System.out.println(string.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate all the name-value pairs and print them in the end:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while (tupleQueryResult.hasNext())  {
    BindingSet bindingSet = tupleQueryResult.next();
    for (Binding binding : bindingSet) {
        // Each Binding contains the variable name and the value for this result row
        String name = binding.getName();
        Value value = binding.getValue();
        result.append(name);
        result.append(" = ");
        result.append(value);
    }
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

You might want to add some separator between the name-value pairs.

Comment: i need to print in inside a textarea it printing only the last string

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable outside your for loop and append it with every iteration. After the loop ends you can print your result.

```
while (tupleQueryResult.hasNext()) {
 BindingSet bindingSet = tupleQueryResult.next();

 String result = ""; // initialize result as empty string

 for (Binding binding: bindingSet) {
  // Each Binding contains the variable name and the value for this result row
  String name = binding.getName();
  Value value = binding.getValue();
  result += name + " = " + value + "\n"; // This will append the row's result to result.
 }
 System.out.println(result);// print after the loop is completed
}
```

If the number of appends to your result variable are more. i.e., bindingSet.size() is large, prefer using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) as these would give faster performance.